# Connect-AzureAD using powershell in Azure Devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am using this code to connect to AzureAD automatically via ADO pipeline, I got this from another post:

````
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '<My service connection name>'
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: |
          Install-Module -Name AzureAD -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -Force
          $context = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile.DefaultContext
          $graphToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.microsoft.com").AccessToken
          $aadToken = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.AuthenticationFactory.Authenticate($context.Account, $context.Environment, $context.Tenant.Id.ToString(), $null, [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.ShowDialog]::Never, $null, "https://graph.windows.net").AccessToken
          Write-Output "Hi I'm $($context.Account.Id)"
          Connect-AzureAD -AadAccessToken $aadToken -AccountId $context.Account.Id -TenantId $context.tenant.id -MsAccessToken $graphToken
          
        azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
      displayName: " Install Azure AD module"```

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: '<My service connection name>'
        ScriptType: 'InlineScript'
        Inline: |
        
          Get-AzureADMSApplication -Filter "DisplayName eq 'My application'" 
       azurePowerShellVersion: 'LatestVersion'
      displayName: "Get Application Name"
````

The code works fine, but on the second task to Get an Application :
I get error in the pipeline as "##[error]You must call the **Connect-AzureAD** cmdlet before calling any other cmdlets."

To avoid this I need to add the code (in the first task) to connect to AzureAD in every azure powershell task.

Is there any way I can avoid this and once connected using Connect-AzureAD code in first task, I do not have to add this code in rest of the tasks?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Next azure powershell task will be executed in a new session, hence you have to use Connect-AzureAD code again to make sure the latter cmdlets can be started, the appearance should be idential with your local machine.

If you'd like to add the code only once, you can put other comlets in same powershell task as an alternative, thanks.