# Automate Connect-AzureAD using powershell in Azure Devops is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet

Tags: azure-devops

I've tried following the suggestion in these posts ([Automate Connect-AzureAD using powershell in Azure Devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60185213/automate-connect-azuread-using-powershell-in-azure-devops/72981414#72981414), [Connect-AzureAD using powershell in Azure Devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68766985/connect-azuread-using-powershell-in-azure-devops), [How to enforce Connect-AzureAD in Azure DevOps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65922440/how-to-enforce-connect-azuread-in-azure-devops)), trying both scripts with token generation and Get-AzContext approach, but both fails, with the following error:

"Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program."

I've tried adding Import-Module as well as Install-Module, both seems to be skipped ...
Any suggestion? Could the error indicate something different, ack of permission or similar?

Thanks
Fabrizio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Connect-AzureAD' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program."

From the error message, it seems that you haven't installed the PowerShell module: `AzureAD`.

You can add an additional PowerShell task and add the script: `Install-Module -Name "AzureAD" -Force` to install the related module.

For example:

```
steps:
- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Azure PowerShell script: InlineScript'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: xx
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: 'Install-Module -Name "AzureAD" -Force'
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion

- task: AzurePowerShell@5
  displayName: 'Run command'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: xx
    ScriptType: InlineScript
    Inline: |
     xxxx
    azurePowerShellVersion: LatestVersion
```

Comment: I've tried adding a second script - why would it not work having the Install-Module in the same script ? - but it fails with the same error. I've also added an Import-Module in the second script but it also fails "Could not load file or assembly"

Comment: I have tested the script and it can work, What kind of agent are you using?

Comment: thanks... changing the agent to Windows definitely helped :-)
Unfortunately I ended up rewriting the entire script using Microsoft Graph API, since it's not possible anymore to assign roles to the ServicePrinciples being AzureAD Graph deprecated